# Microsoft PowerToys key mapping not working in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vsvim

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with VsVim extension to get Vim functionality. I recently found and tried Microsoft PowerToys to remap my escape key with my caps lock key. This works fine with everything beside Visual Studio. When Visual Studio has focus these mappings don't work, but as soon as I click off Visual Studio, the mapping start working again. Is there any reason these mappings through PowerToys would not work in Visual Studio, but work fine elsewhere? [PowerToys Key Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn1zZ.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me it was because Visual Studio was running as admin and PowerToys was not. Just run both as administrator – that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad! That was exactly it and I should have known.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

Coming with an update and additional information. These answers will still work to date. Additionally, you want to make sure that when you install Powertoys that you do so globally. On initial setup you have the option to install for a particular user or globally.

If the above answers aren't solving your problem then you'll want to uninstall and make sure that global installation happened.